# SQL Query help to retrieve rows with or without leading zeroes

Tags: sql, sql-server

Can someone help me with SQL query. I have a below table.

Table:  Customer

| ID | Name | OrderType |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Brate | 012 |
| 2 | Tom | 081 |
| 3 | Shane | 12 |
| 4 | Bill | 123 |
| 5 | David | 051 |
| 6 | Reid | 81 |
| 7 | shohan | 08122 |
| 8 | Amy | 323 |

Requirement is that I need to get all the rows which has ordertype in (012x,081x) with or without leading zeroes.
So on above table, the SQL query should get me rows for id 1,2,3,4,6 and 7)
Can someone help me with the sql query to get this result?
appreciate your help.
6

Comment: Is `OrderType` always a numeric value, or can it have special characters or letters in it?

Comment: Its always a numeric value.

Answer (score 1):

This should give you what you are looking for if    OrderType  is always numeric

```
 select *
    from cust
    where cast(cast(OrderType as int) as varchar) like '81%'
     or cast(cast(OrderType as int) as varchar) like '12%'
```

Cast it to int to remove all the leading zeroes and cast it back to varchar

Answer (score 0):

This query will help you

```
SELECT * FROM `customer` WHERE `OrderType` LIKE '%12%' OR `OrderType` LIKE '%81%'
```

[Check here the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lnavq.png)

Comment: This would bring back records that have `12` or `81` ANYWHERE in them, not just at the beginning. Add a record with `0312` as the `OrderType` and you'll see.

Comment: And your syntax looks like MySQL not SQL Server?

Answer (score 0):

Trim zeroes, pick the first 2 characters and then compare.

```sql
select * 
  from Customer 
 where left(trim('0 ' from OrderType + '!'), 2) in ('12', '81')
```

- Edit

The `!` is there so that it will work correctly if you look for something like '20' for example.